# wp_insert_attachment() dupplicate attachment posts

Tags: images, attachments

I made a function to add an image in WP and attach it to the right post.
The specificity is the input is an url to get the picture.
My problem is when `wp_insert_attachment()` is run I got a dupplicate in Medias and the second one is not attached.

**My function**

```
function save_media_from_url( $image_url, $post_content = "", $post_id = null ){
   $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

   $image_data = file_get_contents( $image_url );

   $filename = basename( $image_url );

   if ( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
       $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
   }
   else {
       $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
   }

   file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

   $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

   $attachment = array(
       'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
       'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
       'post_content' => $post_content,
       'post_status' => 'inherit'
   );

   $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
   var_dump( $attach_id );
   wp_die();
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
   $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file ) 
   wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
   return $attach_id;
```

}

**OUTPUT FOR DEBUGGING**

```
int(188880) <-- attachment id for the first saved ( linked to the right post )
```

The image is saved two times.
The first record in database is linked to the right post and this is the return id but there is a second one saved wihtout any post linked.

Someone know how to fixe this ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause was WPML settings which dupplicates media. :/